# WPF instant validation on keydown

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

How can i trigger update source instantly on keydown. Right now i checking on my commands for `String.NullOrEmpty` for a bound textbox text. The bounded textbox updates the source on textbox leave.
This is a little bit irritating for the users because they always needs to leave the textboxes to update buttons. I can not really remember if the validation triggers instantly, it will solve my problem as well.

```
ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    //Do some stuff
}, () => String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxText));
```

I hope it was clear enough. Leave your comment if not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the `TextBox` you bound your property to to [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx), so it updates the bound field on every keypress instead of on losing focus.

Example:

```
<TextBox Name="itemNameTextBox" 
         Text="{Binding Path=ItemName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```